# Tightening the location of an equilateral triangle given it's contained in a region formed by taking union of five other equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

> If a given equilateral triangle $\Delta$ of side length $a$ lies in the union of five equilateral triangles of side length $b$, show there exist four equilateral triangle of side length $b$ whose union contains $\Delta$
>
> Source: ISI UGB 7/18/2021

Immediately this question led me back to a proof I did in 10th grade about splitting an equilateral triangle into four pieces which are similar (generalised into Sierpinski's triangles):

[image]

Now, here the triangles are joined to each other by common edges but it may just be that either triangles are joined by the vertices in contact or completely disjoint in space. There seem to be a quite a bit of cases to work since we have five triangles.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: I guess since the question asks for union of 5 and says to prove that for union of 4 the triangle would be same, to me it screams 'a' gotta be smaller than '2b'. I guess it'd easy after that.